Policy Regarding Karaite Sect
This question Karaite prostration minhag different? includes the wording:
Is the Karaite prostration minhag uniform to that preserved by other Jews or are there differences?
Does Mi Yodeya have a position on whether Karaites are "other Jews" ? If they are not considered to be Jews, but to be a non-Jewish sect, then questions about Karaite practices are most definitely off-topic.
